# st_intersects of zero area polygon and point returns false

Tags: point-in-polygon, st-intersects, invalid-data

I have the following three geometries:

```
PT: Point(0 0)

LINE: LineString(0 0, 0 10)

POLY: Polygon((0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0))
```

Calling `st_intersects` on LINE and POLY returns true (as though POLY describes Point(0 0).  But calling `st_intersects` on PT and POLY returns false.   I could see POLY being considered an erroneous geometry so false might be the right answer but I would expect `st_intersects(PT,POLY) == st_intersects(LINE,POLY)`

Comment: The polygon is not valid, so I expect you're in the realm of *undefined behavior*, which means that ***any*** response is equally valid. In less formal terms, "Garbage in, garbage out."

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful as we've been trying to match postgis behavior.   But since this is a degenerate case - as you explained - we'll just do what's easy for us.

Answer (score 1):

As Vince pointed out above the polygon

POLY: Polygon((0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0))

is not valid (st_isvalid(POLY) returns false).   Since the polygon is invalid the behavior is undefined so any answer is equally valid.